# Get list (not tree) of dependencies with Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle project with complex dependencies, which I can see using `./gradlew module-name:dependencies`:

```
[...]
testRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'test'.
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core -> 2.11.0
|    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.0
+--- com.google.guava:guava -> 20.0
+--- project :xxx
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx -> 5.1.7.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.7.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.7.RELEASE
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.1.7.RELEASE
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.7.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context -> 5.1.7.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.1.7.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.7.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.7.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.7.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.7.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.1.7.RELEASE
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.7.RELEASE (*)
[...]
```

When I exclude nested dependencies and include them explicitly, the result might look like this:

```
[...]
testRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'test'.
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core -> 2.11.0
|    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.0
+--- com.google.guava:guava -> 20.0
+--- project :xxx
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context -> 5.1.7.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.1.7.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.7.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.7.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.7.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.7.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.1.7.RELEASE
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.7.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-tx -> 5.1.7.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.7.RELEASE
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.7.RELEASE
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.1.7.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.7.RELEASE (*)
[...]
```

In order to see if the *set* of dependencies changed, I'd like to compare *lists* of dependencies. In other words, I'd like to flatten the tree view shown above, so that I can concentrate on differences that are not related to transitive inclusions.

With Maven I can do `mvn dependency:tree` and `mvn dependency:list`. How can I do this using Gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will find some Gradle core tasks to achieve this (maybe some community plugin exist), but you can write your own custom `task` to list dependencies in any format you want ( text, csv, ...)

```
task dependencyList() {
    doLast() {
        configurations.each { configuration ->
            if (configuration.isCanBeResolved()){
                println("Configuration $configuration.name ================================")
                def files = configuration.resolvedConfiguration.getFiles().sort()
                files.forEach{ f -> println("  dep: $f.name")}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem I see is we will not have group ids. We can modify last two lines as:

`def resolvedArtifacts = configuration.resolvedConfiguration.getResolvedArtifacts()`
`resolvedArtifacts.forEach{ f -> println("$f.moduleVersion.id.group:$f.moduleVersion.id.name:$f.moduleVersion.id.version")}`

Comment: `println("$f.moduleVersion.id.group:$f.moduleVersion.id.name:$f.moduleVersion.id.version")}` can be further simplified as `println(f.id.componentIdentifier)`